# How to find a value from a specific element by name?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML file, that looks like this (only a snippet)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
 <Message>
   <Header>
      <Message_Type>RFP</Message_Type> 
      <Message_Date>2020-11-05T09:36:03+01:00</Message_Date> 
      <Sequence_Number>225</Sequence_Number> 
   etc...
```

I am looking for the fastest way to find the value `RFP`.
All i know is the elements name that I need to get a value for.

for example, I get names like `Message_Type` and `Message_Date` and now I need to get the value for these element names.
There are no attributes in the xml

I did some searching and all I can find is how to find an element with a specific attribute, or all elements with a specific value, stuff like that.
It seems like something very basic but i just cant see how to do it.

I tried something like this

```
var headerElements = XElement.Load(fileName).Elements("Header");
var element = headerElements.Where(x => x.Element("Message_Type").Name == "Message_Type");
```

this fills element with the entire `Header` which seems useless to me. I only need the value of one element in ´Header`, not all

So could some kind soul here put me in the right direction on how to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current query is using a `Where` call, which will only filter - it doesn't change which elements you're looking at.

What you want is just the `Element` method itself:

```cs
var messageTypeElements = headerElements.Elements("Message_Type");
```

That will give you all the `<Message_Type>` elements from all the `Header` elements.

If in fact you only have a single `<Header>` and a single `<Message_Type>` then you can use `Element` instead:

```cs
var message = XElement.Load(fileName);
var header = message.Element("Header");
var messageType = header.Element("Message_Type");
```

(The `Element` method will return the *first* element with the given name, or `null` if there aren't any. We don't know whether your program should just throw an exception if there are no headers/message_types, or handle it more gracefully.)